# Metro App cannot open package.appxmanifest

Tags: microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have this Metro App project that I just tried building for the Windows Store.

After completing the buildprocess (with no errors) I can't open the appxmanifest xml file in visual studio anymore. If I select "STORE" > "Edit App Manifest" I get the following error message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I can't open any manifest file in any project now.

Does anybody know whats happening, do I need to reinstall Visual Studio or whats going on?

I'm pretty desperate, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here http://forums.asp.net/t/1836720.aspx/ - so i tried deleting the .suo files from the project, and now it seems to work. I have no clue why that would affect newly created/other/checked out projects, weird behavior indeed?

(Since I am both new to SO and to Visual Studio, I don't know if answering my own question is considered bad practice, if it is, please let me know what I should do instead)

Answer (score 0):

It's an XML file, so you could try to open it with a text editor to figure out if there's an invalid value set somewhere. You could always compare to a default Package.appxmanifest from a new project.

Comment: I tried copying the manifest file from a colleagues version of the project, where it's working, but I still can't open any manifest files.

Comment: When I create a new app, I can't open the manifest file in Visual Studio 2012 (I don't know if it matters but it's a JavaScript project)

Comment: Looks like it might be a Visual Studio problem then. I only have experience with C# projects though. Perhaps, try a reinstall to see if that works?

Comment: Yeah guess I'll have to try that. I was just hoping I wouldn't have to. Thanks for your replies though.

Answer (score 0):

Can your fellow coworker open the manifesting file you're having trouble with?

The first thing to check is to make sure you are running Visual Studio as an admin. (Right click, run as administrator)
Try creating a completely new project. Save it without modifications. Build it. See if you can open the manifesting file in that project. If you can't, try a XAML/C# project instead of JS just to see if something is wrong with the specific project type.

And before you try completely reinstalling, you might try resetting your Visual Studio settings. Make sure to take a backup just in case you need to get your environment back to where it was once you find the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx

Comment: Yes everything is working fine on my coworkers machine (it's Windows 8 running in a VirtualBox, and so is my setup). Running as administrator gives the same result. I'll check out your link, thanks.

Comment: Resetting settings didn't work either, I think I've broken VS :S

Comment: Well, that just sucks. You can always try re-importing your settings to the new install (if you're not afraid it will break it) after the fact.